# Button disabled attribute is not updated correctly when two renders of the same component are performed

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have just started using react-testing-library, so am guessing this is ultimately down to user error, but I am seeing the following behaviour which does not make sense to me.

For the following test run in a freshly created CRA application and using jest-dom 3.0.0 and react-testing-library 5.4.4:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { render } from "react-testing-library";
    import "jest-dom/extend-expect";

    import Component from "./Component";

    describe("Verify UI state based on jobs", () => {
      it("mounts with no previous data", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Component data={[]} />);
        expect(getByTestId("refresh-button")).toBeDisabled();
      });

      it("mounts with previous data", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Component data={["hi"]} />);
        expect(getByTestId("refresh-button")).not.toBeDisabled();
      });
    });

    /*
    const Component = props => {
      return (
        <div>
          <button data-testid="refresh-button" disabled={props.data.length === 0}>
            Refresh
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    */
```

As things are I get the following failure:

Verify UI state based on jobs › mounts with previous data

```
expect(element).not.toBeDisabled()

Received element is disabled:
  <button data-testid="refresh-button" disabled="" />

  13 |   it("mounts with previous data", async () => {
  14 |     const { getByTestId } = render(<Component data={["hi"]} />);
> 15 |     expect(getByTestId("refresh-button")).not.toBeDisabled();
     |                                               ^
  16 |   });
  17 | });
  18 |

  at Object.toBeDisabled (src/Component.test.js:15:47)
```

However, if I disable the first test, the second now passes as it should. If I reorder things, the first test always passes and the second always fails, even if the first test is the 'mount with pervious data' test.

Not sure if this is an issue in the test library, jest-dom or my code, but any advice on how to correctly construct these tests would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs currently state that when [`render`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render) is called ["the queries from `dom-testing-library` are automatically returned with their first argument bound to the rendered container"](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#queries).

As it turns out this is a bug in the documentation as the queries are actually bound to `document.body` if no `container` is passed to `render` (code [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/blob/14b567f87824b2a1b88d238793771e03d03937c4/src/index.js#L10-L15) and [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/blob/14b567f87824b2a1b88d238793771e03d03937c4/src/index.js#L50)).

`react-testing-library` uses the DOM and unless `cleanup` is called between tests the DOM elements from earlier tests will still be there and will be included in later query results.

In this case both `Component` elements exist in `document.body` during the second test and since `getByTestId` queries `document.body` it ends up finding both of them and when it finds more than one it [returns the first one it finds](https://github.com/kentcdodds/dom-testing-library/blob/ab29a47386394fee16db700db8cfd5a6ac03c33e/src/query-helpers.js#L35).

That means that the `Component` from the first test is being returned by `getByTestId` in the second test which causes the test to fail because the first component is disabled.

---

To resolve the issue make sure to call `cleanup` after each test to remove any DOM elements that were added during previous tests:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "react-testing-library";
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";

afterEach(cleanup);  // clean up the DOM after each test

describe("Verify UI state based on jobs", () => {
  it("mounts with no previous data", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Component data={[]} />);
    expect(getByTestId("refresh-button")).toBeDisabled();  // SUCCESS
  });

  it("mounts with previous data", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Component data={["hi"]} />);
    expect(getByTestId("refresh-button")).not.toBeDisabled();  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: I created a [pull request](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/pull/262) to fix the bug

Comment: Update: the creator of `react-testing-library` says that binding the queries to `document.body` is by design so the bug is just in the documentation.  I've updated my answer to reflect that additional info.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I missed the purpose of cleanup and honestly the more detail documentation which clearly states you need to run cleanup between tests. My fault for not going beyond the GitHub page as I started playing with things.